# Javascript overriding rails link_to functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I have a bit of javascript functionality on my application.html.erb page. The page is functioning as a container for other html pages that are being loaded, and it seems to be overriding any link_to paths and/or href tags on the page or any html pages loaded inside of the container. My javascript works correctly and I have installed the jquery-turbolinks gem so I doubt it's an asset pipeline issue.

The culprit seems to be the following javascript because when I comment it out, even though all of my javascript no longer works, I can click on my links again in rails and everything loads properly. I apologize if this is a question that is rudimentary in nature, but I am not so good with javascript at the moment. Anybody have any idea why this is causing such an issue, and what the solution may be?

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    /* Page Load */
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {

    });
```

Html on application.html.erb:

```
<content class="loadContent">
   <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "login", hud_login_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "register", hud_register_path %></li>
   </ul>

<%= yield %>

</content>
```

The full javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    /* Page Load */
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {
        $('div.popup').hide();
        $('div.popup:nth-child('+(event.which-47)+')').show();
        switch(event.which) {
            case 56:
                $('div.popup.friendPics div.friendPicsCont').slimScroll({ 
                    height: '370px',
                    width: '350px',
                    position: 'right',
                    railVisible: false,
                    alwaysVisible: true,
                    railColor: '#4f4c6a',
                    opacity: .7,
                    color: '#4f4c6a'
                });
                break;
        }
    });

    /* Clear Input */
    $('#searchBox').focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("title")) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
        }
    });

    /* Marquee */
    $('#marqueeBlock div.marquee.headline, #adBlock div.marquee.ad').marquee({
        speed: 18000,
        gap: 50,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: 'left',
        duplicated: true,
        pauseOnHover: true
    });

    /* Chat Box */
    $('#chatbox').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            $(this).val("");
            /*$('aside#chat .convo').css({'color':'red'});*/
            var chatbox = $('aside#chat .convo');
            $(chatbox)/('<span>Seth:</span><p>Waddup bro!</p>');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Josh:</span><p>Yoo!<br>Whats up?</p>');
            }, 3000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Seth:</span> <p>Chillin dude<br>wbu?</p>');
            }, 6000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Josh:</span><p>Not too much man, just downloading some new tunes.</p>').scrollTop($(chatbox)[0].scrollHeight);
            }, 9000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Seth:</span><p>Dope. Who??</p>').scrollTop($(chatbox)[0].scrollHeight);
            }, 12000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Josh:</span><p>The new Wolfgang Gartner album :)</p>').scrollTop($(chatbox)[0].scrollHeight);
            }, 15000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Seth:</span><p>OMG YES!</p>').scrollTop($(chatbox)[0].scrollHeight);
            }, 18000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(chatbox).append('<span>Josh:</span><p>Yea, its going down.</p>').scrollTop($(chatbox)[0].scrollHeight);
            }, 21000);
        }
    });

    /* Navigation */
    var wrap = $('content');

    wrap.load('register_temp/');

    /*$('#wheel-link').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#wheel' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });*/
    $('#profileHome-link').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#home' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    /* $('#openLib').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#libPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    }); */
    $('#adBlock div.marquee.ad a').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#sponsorAdPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.music-search-bar a').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#music-search' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#userLibrary .albumPic a').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#artistProfile' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#circle a#homebuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#home' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#searchbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#musicSearch' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#prefbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#prefPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#pointsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#pointsPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#contestsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#contestsPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#cartbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#artistMerch' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#directorybuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#directoryPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circle a#msgsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#msgsPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#homebuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#home' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#searchbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#musicSearch' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#prefbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#prefPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#pointsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#pointsPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#contestsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#contestsPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#cartbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#artistMerch' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#directorybuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#directoryPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#msgsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#msgsPage' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#mapbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#artistCareerMap' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#profitsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#artistProfits' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#circleartist a#statsbuttonLink').on('click', function( e ) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load( href + '#artistStats' )
        .hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    /* Wheel */
    $('#wheel').hide();
    $('#wheelartist').hide();
    $('#wheel-link').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");
        var $this = $(this);
        //alert("Visible: " + pageID);
        $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 0.1,function(){
            if ( $this.hasClass('artist') ) {
                $("#wheelartist").fadeIn(300);
            }
            else {
                $("#wheel").fadeIn(300);
            }
        });

        //$("#libPage").fadeIn("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('*').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        if ($("#wheel, #wheelartist").is(':visible')) {
            $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut(300, function(){
                $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function grow(elem){
        elem.animate({"width" : "+=7", "height":"+=7"}, 200);
    }
    function shrink(elem){
        elem.animate({"width" : "-=7", "height":"-=7"}, 200);
    }
    $('.circle img, .circleartist img').mouseenter(function(){grow($(this));}).mouseleave(function(){shrink($(this));});

    $("img#homebutton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#msgsButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#directoryButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#cartButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#contestsButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#pointsButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#prefButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#searchButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#mapButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#profitsButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("img#statsButton").click(function(){
        $("#wheelartist").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    /* Search */
    $('#search-suggestions').on('click', function( e ){
        $('#search-suggestions').toggle();
        $('#searchBox').val('Search Friends, Artists, and Songs');
    });

    /* Library */
    $('#libPage').hide();
    $('#openLib, #home a.libraryButton, #profile a.libraryButton').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 0.05,function(){
            $("#libPage").fadeIn(300);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#userLibrary a, #userLibrary .libraryCloseX a').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        $("#libPage").fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.libraryScroll1').slimScroll({ 
        height: '380px',
        width: '650px',
        position: 'right',
        railVisible: true,
        alwaysVisible: true,
        //railColor: '#4f4c6a',
        opacity: .7,
        color: '#4f4c6a'
    });
    $('.librarybox2').slimScroll({ 
        height: '380px',
        width: '180px',
        position: 'right',
        railVisible: true,
        alwaysVisible: true,
        //railColor: '#4f4c6a',
        opacity: .7,
        color: '#4f4c6a'
    });

    /* Player */
    /* $('a.musicNote').click(function(){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        //alert("Visible: " + pageID);
        $(pageID).fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $("#libPage").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }); */

    /* Radio */
    $('.radio').css({ 
        'display':'none'
    });
    $('a.radioTower').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 0.1, function(){
            $('.radio').fadeIn(300);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.radio img.image').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        $('.radio').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    /* Live Listening */
    $('.live-listening').css({ 
        'display':'none'
    });
    $('.icon-live-listening img').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 0.1, function(){
            $('.live-listening').fadeIn(300);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.live-listening img.image').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        $('.live-listening').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

It seems this is the culprit. Does anyone know why this would be overriding the default functionality?

```
/* Wheel */
    $('#wheel').hide();
    $('#wheelartist').hide();
    $('#wheel-link').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");
        var $this = $(this);
        //alert("Visible: " + pageID);
        $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 0.1,function(){
            if ( $this.hasClass('artist') ) {
                $("#wheelartist").fadeIn(300);
            }
            else {
                $("#wheel").fadeIn(300);
            }
        });

        //$("#libPage").fadeIn("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('*').on('click', function( e ){
        var pageID = $("div.page:visible");

        if ($("#wheel, #wheelartist").is(':visible')) {
            $("#wheel, #wheelartist").fadeOut(300, function(){
                $(pageID).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: An empty function breaks your entire page? What's in your JS console?

Comment: Please post the **FULL** javascript

Comment: Also worth noting that `<content/>` is not a valid HTML tag.

Comment: @DaveNewton I had isolated what I thought to be the problem. I added the entire javascript.

Comment: @CarlEdwards, cool, but it still loads the html when the javascript is removed, so I don't think that's the issue for right now. She's a work in progress.

Comment: What is the parent of `<content>`? I'm wondering if it isn't one of your `.click` blocks that's trapping your clicks from the parent. You might try commenting out parts of your code until you can isolate the part that is causing the error (JS console will help)

Comment: I'm away from my code at the moment but I will try that and check in. Thank you

Comment: @BryanH, I seem to have isolated the issue. It seems to be within the "wheel" block of code. I have added it to my post. Have any idea why that is causing the issue? And how do you think I should go about maintaining the functionality that was implemented without the javascript overriding the links?